# MySQL Database design with multiple column or single column

Tags: mysql, database, performance, multiple-columns

Hi just a simple question 
I need to store data to database, there are 2 option to show now 
Data : a,b,c,d
1. store a,b,c,d in 1 column, when needed only query and perform splitting in application 
2. store a,b,c,d to 4 different column, can query directly from database
Which option will be better? My concern is split it into 4 different column will make the tables contain many column, does it slow down the performance? And also I am curious is it possible the query is fast but the transfer of data to my application is slow?

Comment: Splitting the content into multiple columns is the first step to normalizing the data. You're going to be extremely limited in your sorting, filtering and selecting options if you store all the data as comma delimited, pipe delimited or some other delimitied value within a single column. MySQL can handle multiple columns. Depending on your data structure, you may be able to normalize the data into multiple tables with a smaller set of columns in each. Hard to say without seeing a sample of your data structure though.

Comment: Split the data into multiple columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL performance is a complicated subject. To the issue you raised:

> My concern is split it into 4 different column will make the tables
>   contain many column, does it slow down the performance?

there is nothing inherently worse, from a performance perspective, to have 4 columns, or 10, or 20, or 50.

Now, that being said, there are things that could impact performance, and probably will if you don't know about them. For example, if you `SELECT * FROM {my_table}` when really you only need to `SELECT a FROM {my_table}`... yeah, that'll impact your performance (although there are arguments to be made in favor of `SELECT * FROM {my_table}` depending on your caching strategy).

Likewise, you'll want to consider LIMIT statements. To your question

> And also I am curious is it possible the query is fast but the
>   transfer of data to my application is slow?

Yes, of course. If you only need 50 rows and your table has 50000, you're gonna want to add limit clauses to your SQL statements, or you'll be sending a lot more data over the wire than you need to be. Memory is faster than disk and disk is faster than network. If you're sending a lot of data over the wire that you don't need, you better believe it's gonna cause performance problems. But again, keep in mind, that has nothing to do with how many columns you have. There is absolutely nothing inherent in the number of columns a table has that affects performance (at least not at the scale that you're talking about and in the way that you are thinking about it)

All of which to say, performance is a complex topic. You should take a look into it, if you're interested. And it sounds like a,b,c, and d are logically different columns, so you should probably go ahead and store them in different columns in MySQL. Hope this helps.

Comment: OK, so can i say that SELECT a from {table} will always be faster than SELECT a,b,c,d from {table }? [a,b,c,d] is actually some value in a list, so i think in my case should be put all into 1 column?

Comment: It does not work the way that you are thinking about it. Suppose that (excluding column overhead) each row of columns a, b, c, and d take up 10 bytes of space ....so each row for a is 10 bytes, each row for b is ten bytes, etc. You have a small amount of overhead for columns in MySQL... but it is a small amount. Now, imagine you want 1000 rows of column a. You could be selecting 1000 x 10 bytes + overhead for column a. Or you could select 1000 x (10 + 10 + 10 + 10) plus overhead for combined column a-d. Think through it a bit... you'll want to split these columns our into 4 separate columns